# Mapping a drive from Windows on a remote Mac via SMB

Tags: server-message-block, cifs, net-use

I have a Mac Mini in one of our offices that is used as a file server locally. I would like for it to serve the files to remote clients as well.

I have File Sharing enabled and Windows Sharing on in the Sharing settings on Mac. There is a shared folder called Shared. I have port 445 open and forwarder on the router that serves as a firewall. Let's say the IP address of the Mac computer is 123.1.123.1.

Now, can I simply "map a drive" from windows via "net use z: \123.1.123.1\Shared" or through Windows Explorer? When I try, I get "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found." The router on this side has 445 port open as well...

Please help. Thank you and Happy Holidays!

Comment: Probably more on topic over at Ask Different or Super User, but search for a question with an answer before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Please, just don't.

Set up a proper VPN that your clients can connect to. Once they do that, they'll be able to connect to the share in the same manner as if they were connected to the local network.